# How to classify frequencies with ranges tending to infinite in R?

Tags: r

I need to classify some frequencies with the bottom and top ranges tending to infinite. Example:

> Less than 1000
>
> 1001 to 5000
>
> 5001 to 10000
>
> 10001 to 50000
>
> More than 50000

How can I do it with R?

Thanks.

Comment: Question is unclear.

Comment: Hi! Please post a reproducible example, what you've tried, and expected output. From what I can see I can suggest you to look at the `?cut` function.

Comment: Use `cut` function, see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/cut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should serve as an example solution.

```
# Data generated
dt<-data.table("Frequency" = sample(x = 1:100000,size = 40))

# New column appended with the Classification
dt[,Class := cut(x = dt$Frequency,breaks = c(-Inf,1000,5000,10000,50000,Inf),labels = c("C1","C2","C3","C4","C5"),right = T)]
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know the Inf constant.